# Show Fingerprint in Picturebox

Tags: c#, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I am developing a functionality that involves saving the fingerprint, for this function I have used the `Digital Persona U 4500 reader.`

Download and install the personal digital SDK and build a windows form c # application.

I added the control whose name: `DigitalPersona Fingerprint Enrollment Control` and in effect captures the fingerprint

[image]

The objective is to be able to visualize the footprint that has been placed in the reader to see in detail how it has been, for this purpose I added a picturebox to be displayed in it and additionally include the following:

public DPFP.Sample Sample = new DPFP.Sample();// instancia la muestra

```
 DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion Convertor = new DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion(); 
 Bitmap bitmap = null;                                                              
 Convertor.ConvertToPicture(sample, ref bitmap);                                    
 PicBoxHuella.Image = bitmap;
```

With the previous action it should show the sample in the picture, but it is not. Valid and identified that the sample arrives in null.

I can't understand the Null value, if when putting a footprint I should capture the value, I would appreciate your guidance a bit on the subject.
[image]

Comment: Hola, cómo obtuviste el control en Español? El mío aparece en ingles. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the **`OnCaptured`** event, you get the image data from the `Fiv` en `Data.Views`:

Note: `pbFingerprint` is an *PictureBox* where the image will display.

```
    private void enrollment_OnCaptured(EnrollmentControl enrollmentControl, CaptureResult captureResult, int fingerPosition)
        {
            if (captureResult.ResultCode == Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (captureResult.Data != null)
                {
                    foreach (Fid.Fiv fiv in captureResult.Data.Views)
                    {
                        pbFingerprint.Image = CreateBitmap(fiv.RawImage, fiv.Width, fiv.Height);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a bitmap from raw data in row/column format.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes"></param>
    /// <param name="width"></param>
    /// <param name="height"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Bitmap CreateBitmap(byte[] bytes, int width, int height)
    {
        byte[] rgbBytes = new byte[bytes.Length * 3];

        for (int i = 0; i <= bytes.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            rgbBytes[(i * 3)] = bytes[i];
            rgbBytes[(i * 3) + 1] = bytes[i];
            rgbBytes[(i * 3) + 2] = bytes[i];
        }
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        for (int i = 0; i <= bmp.Height - 1; i++)
        {
            IntPtr p = new IntPtr(data.Scan0.ToInt64() + data.Stride * i);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbBytes, i * bmp.Width * 3, p, bmp.Width * 3);
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        return bmp;
    }
```